# Prove 3 coin toss events as pairwise independent but not mutual

Tags: probability

Totally lost of where to start with this question :

Suppose you roll three distinguishable fair dice and call the resulting numbers a, b, and c. Define events X= “a+b is even", ”Y= “b+c is even", and Z= “a+c is even”.  Prove that these three events are pairwise independent but not mutually independent.

Right now, this is how I understand the difference between pairwise independence and mutual independence.

,, are mutually independent if
$(∩∩)=()()()$

But this is not the case for pairwise independence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The definition of mutual independence for three events  (using $A,B$ to denote $A\cap B$ is:
$$
P(A,B)=P(A)P(B), \qquad P(B, C)=P(B)P(C),\qquad P(C,A)=P(C)P(A),\\
P(A,B,C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)
$$
So there are four conditions to check, not just the three way one you listed. For pairwise, you only need the first three.

For mutual independence of $n$ events, there are $2^n-n-1$ conditions, one for each subset of the events.

---

Note that $a+b,a+c,$ and $b+c$ are all even iff and only if $a,b,c$ are all even or $a,b,c$ are all odd. Therefore,

$$
P(X,Y,Z)=P(a,b,c\text{ all even})+P(a,b,c\text{ all odd})=(1/2)^3+(1/2)^3=1/4.
$$
However,
$$
P(X)=P(a,b\text{ both even})+P(a,b\text{ both odd})=(1/2)^2+(1/2)^2=1/2,
$$
so
$$
P(X)P(Y)P(Z)=(1/2)^3=1/8. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Z= X\odot Y$ (coincidence operator).

COnsqeuently $P X = P Y  = PZ = {1 \over 2}$ and
$P[X \cap Y \cap \bar Z| = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we've been given a collection of events $X_1,X_2,...,X_n.$

The events are mutually independent if $$P\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n X_k\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n P(X_k),$$ and pairwise independent if for all $j,k$ with $1\le j<k\le n$ we have $$P(X_j\cap X_k)=P(X_j)\cdot P(X_k).$$

So, you'll need to show the following: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)\\P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C)\\P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)\\P(A\cap B\cap C)\neq P(A)P(B)P(C)$$